# ngautocomplete devextreme is lagging to show dropdown and sometimes not load

Tags: javascript, angular, devexpress, devextreme

Devexteme ngautocomplete is lagging and drop down is not showing after api call everytime search is performed Below is code

```
<dx-autocomplete #autocompleteRef [dataSource]="employeesIAM" valueExpr="login" [grouped]="false" [searchExpr]="['login','firstName','lastName']"
        label="Enter login or name" labelMode="floating" [showClearButton]="true" [minSearchLength]="3"
        (onSelectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event);"  groupTemplate="group"
        (onValueChanged)="search($event)" 
        itemTemplate="item" [wrapItemText]="true" [searchTimeout]="300" >
        </dx-autocomplete>
```

```
this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((query:string)=> this._crewService.getEmployeeList(query))
    ).subscribe(res => {
      this.employeesIAM = [];
      this.employeesIAM = res;
      this.employeesIAM.map(abc => abc.login = `${abc.login}  ${abc.firstName} ${abc.lastName}`);
      this.employeesIAM.map(abc => abc.Name = `${abc.firstName} ${abc.lastName}`);
    });

onValueChanged(data: any) {
    if (data != null && data.length >= 3) {
      this._crewService.getEmployeeList(data).subscribe(res => {
        this.employeesIAM = [];
        this.employeesIAM = res;
        this.employeesIAM.map(abc => abc.loginAndName = `${abc.login}  ${abc.firstName} ${abc.lastName}`);
        this.employeesIAM.map(abc => abc.Name = `${abc.firstName} ${abc.lastName}`);
      });
    }
  }
```

Can you suggest to prevent this lagging